# Where is folder eosio-wallet located for Elementary OS?

Tags: cleos

I am going through the tutorials now 
https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/learn-about-wallets-keys-and-accounts-with-cleos

It says that there is a folder

```
The file for this wallet is named default.wallet. By default, keosd stores wallets in the ~/eosio-wallet folder
```

However, it is not in the home directory for the Elementary OS.

Where is this eosio-wallet folder?

Comment: What is the operating system? Setup?

Comment: I am using Elementary OS, which is a linux based on ubuntu

Comment: I think I have found my wallets here
/tmp/eosio/data/

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can search for files in linux by using the `find` command:

```
find / -name eosio-wallet
```

Please let us know the result of this search

Answer (score 0):

In your home directory. "~" indicates the user's home directory

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it is not there